# Best practice for multiple .Count usages

Tags: c#

So, which of the following 2 code blocks is "best" in regards to performance/best practise etc.

Calling the `.Count` property multiple times at each usage.

```
List<string> myStrings = new List<string>();
myStrings.Add("foo");
myStrings.Add("bar");

if (myStrings.Count >= 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myStrings.Count);
}
```

Storing the count once and reusing it since we can assume there will be no changes to the list.

```
List<string> myStrings = new List<string>();
myStrings.Add("foo");
myStrings.Add("bar");

int myCount = myStrings.Count;
if (myCount >= 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myCount);
}
```

Comment: There will no difference. JIT will optimize it anyway.

Comment: In this case the optimizer can prove `myStrings` won't be used in another thread, but does it actually make this optimization?

Comment: IMHO, hard to say without context. Does few CPU instructions matter to performance of you application? Do you intend to generalize the question / answer for single threaded and multithreaded applications (i.e. where `List.Count` may change between the two calls)? Performance is subjective and as for best practice.. Best practice is to understand and implement what gives you correct semantics for **your scenario**. Any other blind advice *can* be recipe for trouble in some cases. Example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770138/tostring-and-string-concatenation-unexpected-behavior

Comment: When multithreading each of the given code examples could potentially provide a very different result, so I would assume that you would design your code and use the example (and potentially locks) that suited how you wanted the code to actually work. So assume the question is for single threaded purposes but do mention any multi-threading points of interest perhaps? 

Well, it is possible that this example could be changed to require a thousand '.Count' checks as part of a loop so CPU instructions could certainly have a large impact there.

Comment: @VikasGupta While best practise is based on a case by case basis, there are still recommendations that can be made based on situations x, y and z. My specific example/usage of this is very wide as I seem to encounter it every few days in a slightly different scenario each time so I figured knowing the best practise for the most common scenario would then allow that to be applied to the other scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `List<T>` it is not particularly important, since the List stores its count and is able to return it cheaply.

For `Count` extension method on an arbitrary `IEnumerable`, you had better use a temporary variable to avoid calling `Count` multiple times.  This is because the `Count` extension method has to walk the entire collection (it will detect `IList` and use the fast Count, but e.g. `yield return` enumerables don't implement `IList`).

Comment: Very good answer, thanks. So you recommend using the second method for an IEnumerable but the first for a list?

Comment: @Adrian773: Safer to just use the temporary variable in both cases.  The exception is for the `Length` of an array... there you should use `Length` in a for loop control expression, not a local variable that contains the same value, because the JIT compiler depends on seeing an access to `Length` to elide bounds checks inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

`myStrings.Count` doesn't actually count anything, it just takes the stored count and returns it. So it will be more or less the same.

The comments about being identical because the optimizer will optimize it away may be true for such a simple case, but will definitely not be true if the compiler can't be certain the list isn't being accessed from another thread.

Comment: I am fairly certain the runtime has the right to optimize the call even if it can't prove that another thread will not access it. After all this is why we have locks, volatile, etc. - to tell the runtime what can be optimized and what should wait for synchronization.

Comment: Just to clarify, "more or less the same != "identical"? When you mention the optimization, are you meaning that the "optimizer" will simply re-use the result it received from the first call?

Very eager to find out if @Stilgar is correct also, so does anybody else want to weigh in here?