# ToString and string concatenation - unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, resharper

According to the internet when you do

```
String someString = "" + object1 + object2 + object3;
```

`ToString()` is called on each of the objects.

But this is not happening!
This code:

```
String a = "a" + foo;
String b = "b" + foo.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Prints:

```
a
b("key":"foo")
```

How is it possible?

I made Resharper full cleanup on whole project and it broke code in some place because it removed `ToString()` in such string concat!! Lost many hours..

**Edit:**
This problem happened in one of small libraries I was using. I cannot provide very short one-file code that will reproduce this but I have created small project with this library and uploaded to github:

https://github.com/Vistritium/ToStringCSObjectConcat
https://github.com/Vistritium/ToStringCSObjectConcat/blob/master/TestString/Program.cs

The library is 1178 lines long.

Comment: SO is not site to solve coding puzzles (question looks like one in current state). If you need help please show small complete (preferably compilable) sample.

Comment: `a` might be correct if the objects return String.Empty. `b` looks like an anonymous Type was created.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I have created shortest possible project where I could reproduce this and uploaded to github.

Comment: You said 'according to the internet' that `ToString` is called, but your own example seems to disprove this. Perhaps the internet is wrong, or more likely there's more rules in this scenario than always calling `ToString`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen if you have provided an [implicit operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) converting your class to a string, for instance:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator string(Foo foo)
    {
        return foo == null ? string.Empty : foo.Value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var str = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Key))
        {
            if (str.Length > 0)
                str += ";";
            str += ("Key=" + Key);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Value))
        {
            if (str.Length > 0)
                str += ";";
            str += ("Value=" + Value);
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

In that case:

```
    string a = "a" + new Foo { Key = "foo", Value = "" };
    string b = "b" + new Foo { Key = "foo", Value = "" }.ToString();

    Debug.WriteLine(a); // Prints "a".
    Debug.WriteLine(b); // Prints "bKey=foo
```

You could also get this effect if you have [overloaded the `+` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for `string` and `Foo`.

**Update**

From the C# Language Specification, [7.2.2 Operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691324%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> All unary and binary operators have predefined implementations that are automatically available in any expression. In addition to the predefined implementations, user-defined implementations can be introduced by including operator declarations in classes and structs [(Section 10.9)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664461(v=vs.71).aspx). User-defined operator implementations always take precedence over predefined operator implementations: Only when no applicable user-defined operator implementations exist will the predefined operator implementations be considered.

That's why the custom logic gets invoked in preference to the standard logic.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know C# supports implicit conversions like Scala. So it turns out that Resharper cleanup can break your code and it's Resharper's fault. Be careful!

Comment: First case (preferring "string + string" over "string + object" when there is implicit conversion to string) is covered in section [7.4.2.3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691339%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) - "If an implicit conversion from T1 to T2 exists, and no implicit conversion from T2 to T1 exists, C1 is the better conversion." - in this case "If an implicit conversion from `string` to object` exists, and no implicit conversion from `object` to `string` exists, implicit conversion of custom time to `string` is the better conversion."

Answer (score 1):

I just did this and it is working perfectly

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var o = new x ();
    string s = "ff" + o;

    Console.WriteLine(s);

}

public class x {

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "This is string";
    }
}
```

Prints

> ffThis is string

Which tells me that you do something wrong. I mean, not as much that you do wrong as much as you expect something different than your objects produce in `ToString`

Comment: I have created custom simple case myself as well and it worked. But it doesn't work in some cases like the one I uploaded.

Comment: @Vistritium Again, it works as designed. It is whatever you uploaded does something. For example, if I override `ToString` and throw exception in there, I will get exception on concatenation.